# problem in PDF file display and download using sails js

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, pdfkit

I am using sails JS.I generated a PDF using pdfkit. No problems with the generated PDF when opened in pdf reader. when I send the same pdf to browser from my controller, It is not getting displayed sometimes. Sometimes it's getting displayed after 2 to 3 refresh clicks and sometimes it is getting displayed. It's behaving weird. No errors too. I am using chrome.

```
var file = fs.createReadStream('test1.pdf');
       res.header('content-type', 'application/pdf');
       //res.header('content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=quote.pdf',);
       file.pipe(res);
```

I uncomment the 3rd line when i want the file to be downloaded.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue. The problem is i am saving a doc using pdfkit to a file name 'test1.pdf' everytime. so it's creating a problem sometimes. I resolved it by directly sending doc element to browser.
doc.pipe(res);

This is working so fine. Thanks